# jq modify value based on existing value of the attribute

Tags: json, jq

I have an array of JSON objects,

```
[
  {
    "id": "100006578",
    "name": "Someone",
    "category": "frontend"
  },
  {
    "id": "100005436",
    "name": "Someone",
    "category": "backend"
  }
]
```

I want to replace the value of the id field based on its existing value. I want to use the existing value (100005436) of the id field and replace it with a new value (200005436) based on the existing value. Basically, I just want to replace the first character of the string in the existing value. The output should be like

```
[
  {
    "id": "200006578",
    "name": "Someone",
    "category": "frontend"
  },
  {
    "id": "200005436",
    "name": "Someone",
    "category": "backend"
  }
]
```

I tried a lot of stuff. But still struggling with jq.
Nearest logical option I tried was to increment it
 `jq '.externalId|map(.id+100000000)' fileWithJsonObject`
but it doesn't work because it is a string.

I'm really finding it hard to get the substitute expression that can take an existing value and only replace a particular part from it. There are many answers on stack overflow that talk about replacing the value of the key based on externally supplied value but I want to take the exiting value,  modify it and replace it.
The nearest I have gone till now is the following but unfortunately, it is not complete:
`jq '.externalId|to_entries|map(if .id then sub(*regex*; *tostring*))' fileWithJsonObject`

I'm looking for a way to get to the right regex and how can I provide/use the current value of the id attribute in substitute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm looking for a way to get to the right regex

```
.[].id |= sub("^."; "2")
```

(You could drop the "^" but it makes the intention abundantly clear.)

More generally:

```
.[].id |= (. as $id | sub("^."; $id[0:1] | tonumber+1 | tostring)
```

Comment: This works but I want to take a value from the id field and replace the first character of that value. And what I want to replace with I want to derive from the existing value of the id field. at the place of "2" can I give an expression referring to the current value of id.

Comment: you are awesome! :-)

Answer (score 5):

> replace the first character of the string ...

A concise solution using `map`:

```
map(.id |= "2" + .[1:])
```

or more generally:

```
map(.id |= (.[0:1]|tonumber+1|tostring) + .[1:])
```

Even more concisely:

```
[].id |= "2" + .[1:]
```

etc...

Answer (score 1):

Map thru the array, replace each element's "id" with a new value. In this case, convert original value's type to numeric, add 100 million and convert back to string.

In other words,

```sh
jq 'map( . + { "id": ( .id | tonumber + 100000000 ) | tostring } )'
```

Comment: if only the first character is to be replaced, you can use `jq 'map( . + { "id": ( "3" + .id[1:] ) } )'`

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' about parenthesis, sorry it was my bad. I'm deleting my previous comment.